# How to display Calendar event

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I have been working on a project where the calendar events are collected from google calendar and display it.
The process have done is having google sign-in and sign-out button.
Don't know how to move further!

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see below function that gets the events from Google Calendar using Apps Script. Apologies for not using ReactJS, but I am still hoping this can help you as the logic is still the same.

```
function getCalendarEvents() {
  
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var calID = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_jetel4kln5s4a9ola0h67jro6g@group.calendar.google.com"); //You can get the calendar ID through right clicking your Calendar->Settings and sharing->Integrate Calendar->Calendar ID
  var calEvents = calID.getEvents(new Date("11/01/2020 12:00 AM"), new Date("11/30/2020 11:59 PM"));
  
  var lastRowEvent = spreadSheet.getLastRow();
  spreadSheet.getRange(2, 1,lastRowEvent-1,5);  //For this line of code, it deletes the content you last had to make the row and column of your spreadsheet available for new added events(if ever you deleted some).
  
  //Loop through the events you have in your Google Calendar
  for(var i = 0; i<calEvents.length;i++) {
    var titleEvents = calEvents[i].getTitle();
    var startDate = calEvents[i].getStartTime();
    var endDate = calEvents[i].getEndTime()
    var location = calEvents[i].getLocation();
    var description = calEvents[i].getDescription();
    
    //having i+2 so you can go through the second row without overlapping the headers per column
    spreadSheet.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(titleEvents);
    spreadSheet.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(startDate);
    spreadSheet.getRange(i+2, 2).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"); //setting the correct format for date and time 
    spreadSheet.getRange(i+2, 3).setValue(endDate);
    spreadSheet.getRange(i+2, 3).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"); //setting the correct format for date and time 
    spreadSheet.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(location);
    spreadSheet.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue(description);
  }
}
```

**Here's my reference and guide in achieving this output:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXG-i_sG8CI&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemv62NNC5bXLR0CzeaIj5bcw&index=10